# Inter-annotator agreemnet on a dataset with no annotator id

Tags: python, agreement-statistics

I have a dataset of annotations like the following,

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({
   "unit_num": ['a','b','c','d'],
   "rating_1":[0,2,1,1],
   "rating_2":[0,3,1,0],
   "rating_3":[0,0,0,4],
   "rating_4":[0,4,0,0]
})
```

the annotators were given 4 sentences to rate by giving a number between (1-4). the unit_num shows the 4 sample sentences, and the other columns are the ratings, and for each rating, I have 'how many times annotators chose a rating per sentence'.

I would like to calculate an agreement measure for my dataset, and I have seen that most people recommend Krippendorf's alpha. But almost all calculations I have found(implemented in python) require the annotator Id, which I do not have. I was wondering if I am there are any other ways of calculating agreement or should I take other approaches for my specific case?

Comment: Shouldn't the columns for the ratings sum to the same total number of ratings? Why they aren't?

Comment: the values in the rating columns show the frequency of that rating being chosen by the annotators. for each sentence I had 4 annotators, so the sum of each unit rating should be 4 (4 annotators per unit, 4 units, ratings from (1-4) )

Comment: OK, but this is not what your example shows. In your example sentence "a" has 0 for all ratings, so it wasn't rated by anyone?

Comment: exactly, if it is zero, it means none of the annotators chose that rating

Comment: So for sentence "a" none of the annotators chose none of the ratings, i.e. it was not rated?